# Wants to add icon options in bottom sheet similar to Whatsapp New group page

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

Open Whatsapp new group page, click on that group icon, bottomsheet appears and it shows list of installed camera/icon related options.My question is how we write those permissions(if we write) to add those camera/icon related options in our app? I want to add a similar looking bottomsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a bottom sheet as you can get the same functionality from a Chooser Intent.

```
//Create an intent
            final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");

            //Create any other intents you want
            final Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            //Add them to an intent array
            Intent[] intents = new Intent[]{cameraIntent};

            //Create a choose from your first intent then pass in the intent array
            final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Choose icon");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intents);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 101);
```

You will need to capture the input by overriding onActivityResult.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to capture the input. For e.g. camera input (I am new to android and don't know how to handle the input).@Glurt
& the above code worked :).